# Best way of keeping logs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, rds

What would be the best way to keep logs?

Possible solutions that I can think of are below

1. Create Log Table which contains a field that saves data in json format
2. Create a table which has identical structure with a table that saves data

Currently, I am using Solution 1, however, I wonder if there is a better way to keep logs.

Here is the example:

Table `Books`

```
| id | name            | created_at | price | author         | reputation |
|----|-----------------|------------|-------|----------------|------------|
| 1  | about korea     | 2018-01-01 | 1000  | korean         | 10         |
| 2  | kimchi vs sushi | 2018-01-01 | 5000  | natural korean | 20         |
| 3  | i love america  | 2018-02-03 | 6000  | kim jong un    | 30         |
```

Whenever there is a change in Books, I create a record in `BooksLog` to keep track of changes like below. Keeping log like this would be flexible, so that even if the field changes, it would not majorly be affected, but this way has performance issue.

```
| id | books_id | row                                                                                                                       |
|----|----------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 1        | { id : 1, name : "about korea", created_at : "2018-01-01", price : 1000, author : "korean", reputation : 10 }             |
| 2  | 2        | { id : 2, name : "kimchi vs sushi", created_at : "2018-01-01", price : 5000, author : "natural korean", reputation : 20 } |
| 3  | 3        | { id : 3, name : "i love america", created_at : "2018-01-01", price : 6000, author : "kim jong un", reputation : 30 }     |
```

Comment: Why use ```row``` column?
You aready(books_id) use foreign key
later... If you need Books info, You can refer to the books table using books_id.

If you saved json format!

If JavaScript.

```javascript
let variable = {a: 1, b: 2}
JSON.stringify(variable)
```

If Python

```python
import json
variable = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
variable = json.dumps(variable)
```

Here are the methods I use in python and JavaScript.

Comment: I am trying to save old data of `Books` in the row of `BooksLogs`. okay ?

Comment: what is old data? I don't understand what is old data. example. If you do not sell books anymore, is it delete on Books table and save on BookLogs table?